# Control the string order with regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

`<keyword> <id> <title> <where> <prize>`
*Ex: Regex `10 Blablabla Miami 1250`*

Keyword: text

id: number

title: text

prize: number (like 150)

It's about SMS integration. This string comes from web service. I need to control this order. There is no character limit for texts. Just `<where>` must be 15 character. Maybe I can use regex but how is it? Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by controlling string order ? Regex come before 10, 10 come before Blablabla... ?

Comment: Yes Coder, I want to check (control) the string order. Order must be like <keyword> <id> <title> <where> <prize>

Comment: How do you know where `<title>` ends and `<where>` begins?

Comment: The Regex lingua is something like that "something followed by something followed by something else", so yes, the regex will "tell" that the matches are in order.

Comment: there are spaces between the tags. One tag is just one word. I mean for <keyword>, it must be just one word, otherwise it's fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
^\w+\s+\d+\s+\w+\s+\w{1,15}\s+\d+$
```

Which matches the string if it has the next format:

```
<word - keyword>
<one or more spaces>
<number - id>
<one or more spaces>
<word - title>
<one or more spaces>
<word not longer than 15 symbols - where>
<one or more spaces>
<number - prize>
```